# How to create a universal method in PHP for determine the number of rows in mysql?

Tags: pdo

How to create a universal method in PHP for determine the number of rows in mysql?
Someone please help? Thank you.

## My method (does not work)

```
public function countRow($table, $array)
{
     $bef = implode(', ', array_keys($array));
     $aft = implode(', ', array_fill(0, sizeof($array), '=?'));
     $sql = 'SELECT '.$bef.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$aft.' LIMIT 1';
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute(array_values($array));
     return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

## Example array (3 key and 3 value)

```
$array = array('name'   => $_POST['name'],
               'pass'   => secure($_POST['pass']),
               'status' => 0);
```

## Or example array (1 key and 1 value)

```
$array = array('single' => $_POST['one']);
```

## Call method

```
$this->countRow('tablename', $array);
```

Comment: But if you add `LIMIT 1`, wouldn't this always return 0 or 1?

Comment: Why do you want such a method?